# How to check if process is not responding?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

Is there any possibility to check from code if another process is not responding?

The problem is even if the app is crashed and on the Manager's list is marked as 'Not Responding', the Process.Responding property is still returning 'true'.

The 'Exited' event and function 'WaitForExit' are do any action if the process is- what is clear- exited. So it's not the point.

Problem in two words; I need to know that the application is crashed. How to check it from the code?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Does the other process have a (visible) main window? This is required by `Process.Responding`, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.responding.aspx

Comment: my application needs to check the other process, defined by user at the runtime. so i don't know if it's for example a console app.

Comment: Other than Task Managers heuristic for GUI apps (IIRC: does it process a WN_NULL message in a timely fashion) there is no general way to determine "hung" (e.g. it could be waiting for something or busy doing work).

Answer (score 23):

**There is no general solution to this problem.**

It is impossible to tell if a particular process is hanging or not, because the term "hanging" is entirely dependent upon the context of the process that is executing.

The hanging process will always do what it was coded to do. The developer may have coded it badly, but Windows can't make assumptions about what is right/wrong.

Possible ideas to try might be:

1. The [Process.Responding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.responding.aspx) call will indicate whether or not a process that is executing a windows message loop is responding.
2. One possible solution for the more general case might be to poll the memory usage for the process at intervals and if it doesn't change after enough time, assume that it is hung. You could do this with `Process.WorkingSet64`. However, I expect that this would cause a number of false positives - stable processes that are not processing anything might appear to be hanging. It would also cause false negatives where a hanging process that had a memory leak would appear to be doing something useful, when in fact it was stuck in a loop.
3. If the process writes to the StandardError/StandardOutput streams (as many console applications do), then you could try listening for such output: `Process.BeginOutputReadLine` and `Process.BeginErrorReadLine`. If there is no such output within a given period, you might deduce that it has hung.

But you're not going to find anything that works in the general case.

Comment: I looked quite a while over the web with the attempt to find out if a threaded CMD.exe process has returned its final message or not ( via `RedirectStandardInput` and `RedirectStandardOutput` ) , nothing seemed to work: Handle/Responding/thread.ThreadState...
So i solved it by calling `StandardInput.WriteLine` twice and passing my custom string the second time. This way i could invoke an event that told me the process is IDLE. Also using `while(true)` to contentiously run with a fixed interval its possible to know if an outside command was received and queue it for execution.

Comment: So how does Task Manager do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is one solution that will work for some use cases. If your process is a fire -> process -> exit type of process, then all you have to do is monitor the CPU cycles.

The downsides are, of course, this won't detect hung processes immediately, and it won't work if your process is event based and runs at idle for periods of time. That being said, for some scenarios this should do the trick.

```
TimeSpan processorTime;
public async Task<bool> MonitorProcess(Process activeProcess, int timeoutSeconds = 30) {
    int hungCycles = 0;
    while (!activeProcess.HasExited)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        if (activeProcess.TotalProcessorTime == processorTime)
            hungCycles++;
        else
        {
            processorTime = activeProcess.TotalProcessorTime;
            hungCycles = 0;
        }
        if (hungCycles > timeoutSeconds)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```