# Azure Remote app how to end a stuck process

Tags: azure, remoteapp

We have an app that we are testing to move over to the Azure RemoteApp.

Currently the application creates word documents and merges them. Sometimes a word window will hang in this process.
Currently what we would do with RDP is end the `winword.exe` process for that user name and our `program.exe` and relaunch to correct this. (if you end the RDP it will still be stuck when you reconnect) As far as I am aware when using the Azure RemoteApp we do not have the same access to do this as this.
I have discovered that there is a power shell cmdlet for the remote app, is it possible to end the process with

```
gwmi -query "select * from win32_process where name='PROCESSNAME.exe'" | %{if($_.GetOwner().User -eq 'USERNAME'){$_.terminate()}}
```

Or is there a way with Azure RemoteApp to end the process through the service?
I have tried several different searches to get the answer to this and nothing seems to address it.

Comment: If you press Ctrl-Alt-End while the application is focused, you will get a screen from where you can launch the Task Manager to kill a process. If you are looking for a programmatic method, you can install any software on the template image and that can periodically check if the process has crashed (there is no easy way to check if it is not responding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500634/how-to-check-if-process-is-not-responding ). And your agent can answer to keyboard shortcuts (i.e.: Ctrl-Alt-R or something would restart your program).

Comment: Thank you very much. Just to be sure Ctrl-Alt-End works in the azure environment?

Comment: Ctrl-Alt-End works in any RemoteApp or Remote Desktop session (regardless whether it is Azure RemoteApp or just on-premise RemoteApp or Remote Desktop)

Answer (score 1):

User cdavid seems to have answered this in the comments above. I was unaware of Ctrl+Alt+End (Ctrl+Opt+End on mac) to end processes on Azure Virtual Desktop and RDP. Saved me during after-hours work when I REALLY needed to kill a process. Thanks!