# How to know if the process is busy

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I need to find out how can I check **if process is busy right now**. I didn't found anything in the properties of C# Process class.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's your definition of busy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if process is not responding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500634/how-to-check-if-process-is-not-responding)

Comment: Rob, I mean that I don't know if process is working right now or not. If it does nothing - I would like to kill it.

Comment: Tobbe, that question is not related to my question

Comment: Then define what you mean by busy if not "doing something all the time whilst not responding".

Comment: Well - all processes are working while they're running. At the very least, they'll still be processing messages from the operating system. Again; you need to be specific about 'working'. Is the following 'working' code? `while (true) {}`?

Comment: Do you own the other process code?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the following:

```
if (Process.GetProcessesByName("process_name").Length > 0)
{
    // Is running
}
```

You can change the process name here with your process

Or if you want to check a no of processes then do the following:

```
Process[] process = Process.GetProcesses();    
foreach(Process theprocess in process)
{
   if(theprocess.Length>0)
   {
       //process running
   }
   else
   {
      //not running
   }
}
```