# How can I determine whether a specific process is responsive?

Tags: c, linux, windows, macos, process

I'm working on something that's basically a task manager. I have a working prototype but now I'd like to be able to show applications that are not responsive.

Are there APIs that can tell me whether this is the case under Window, macOS, Linux? I need to do this without the cooperation of the processes, so I can't just send a custom message and wait for a response.

Preferably C, but I can work with Obj-C & co.

Comment: Pretty broad categories, no code, asking for help developing a concept.  Not sure what can be done with this.  If you have a working prototype, and there is a problem with it, (eg, it is unresponsive.) show it, perhapse as a [mcve].  Maybe it will inspire some ideas, but the form of the question as is, is off-topic here.

Comment: as a start you might want to check these links: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/248527 for linux and https://stackoverflow.com/a/5229638/5639126 for windows.

Comment: For Windows apps that own a window there is [IsHungAppWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-ishungappwindow).

Comment: Thanks @secret squirrel. The Unix process state is not very usable (it basically covers one of the many cases of hung processes) but the Windows version can be useful.

Comment: Thanks @dxiv. I should be able to find the `HWND` with a little effort, so this would probably solve the issue for Windows.

Comment: @ryyker I realize that the definition of what's off-topic has changed since I started using StackOverflow. Where would you suggest asking such questions, though?

Comment: [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) comes to mind.  This site though is pretty focused on helping to solve actual codeing - software problems, i.e. _I wrote this code_ `"_put some code here hopefully in the form of a_"` [mcve], _I provided this input and expected this output, but got this instead_ type of questions.