# Kill form if suspend or freeze or sleep

Tags: c#, winforms

I searching a lot about this I can't find guide or way ..
I'm using form to contact my server.

with processor hack I can make suspend .exe file
like that

[image]

I want to keep checking my exe or form if its freeze or suspend .. form automatic exit

EDIT : guys I found a way to check it but its with id process .. I want make it with name of process

```
Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(8175);
    if(proc.Threads[0].WaitReason == ThreadWaitReason.Suspended)
    {             
    MessageBox.Show("Process is suspend !");
        //process is suspended
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like the halting problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if process is not responding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500634/how-to-check-if-process-is-not-responding)

Comment: @Enigmativity yes look like

Comment: @Jesse i have try it .. nothing happen

Comment: I guess the real thing to spend your time on is finding why it's freezing in the first place

Comment: @Charlieface umm form not freezing .. I mean if some1 trying to suspend it or freeze it to put anything or open something I don't want to open 
that's why I want if form suspend or freeze or sleep anything like that automatic exit app

Comment: Well if it's suspended it can't do anything. Unless you have another process doing the check using some kind of IPC. But that process could be suspended as well...... Why do you care anyway, why is somebody suspending your threads?

Comment: @Charlieface in this program processor hacker if form suspended .. meaning app not exit .. its will just freeze till he resume it .. I making anti cheat with form like close progs names and etc..

Comment: But what happens if somebody cheats the anti-cheat mechanism? You can't stop everything, especially if the user has admin access.

Comment: @Charlieface ofc There some1 will crack it .. but you can say .. do the best as you can !

Comment: @Dona - The [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) is impossible to solve.

Comment: @Enigmativity what you think if can check it with C++ codeblock dll ?

Comment: @Dona - Sorry, I'm saying you can't do it no matter what.

Comment: @Enigmativity nope i already saw people have done it before ..

Comment: @Enigmativity There noway to check if process is suspend or not ?
or reading what status is from task manager ?

Comment: guys I found a way to check it but its with id process .. I want make it with name of process `
 (`Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(8175);
            if (proc.Threads[0].WaitReason == ThreadWaitReason.Suspended)
            {
               
MessageBox.Show("Process is suspend !");
                //process is suspended
            }`?)