# What API to grab windows process status?

Tags: windows, winapi, delphi-xe, taskmanager

I need to write a small application to monitor the **status** of a Windows process using Delphi or C++. A call that will show me Process Status, particularly when the status is 'not responding'.

What windows API must I use to accomplish this?

What I want is essentially what you can see in Task Manager - ***Status*** :

[image]

I have not tried anything yet, since I don't know what API to use.

(My old profile 'Vector' is lost - I am not really a newbe. Experienced programmer and Stack Overflow participant.)

Comment: What identifying information do you have for the process, to separate it from processes you aren't interested in?  HANDLE?  Process ID?  EXE filename?

Comment: Also note that the "Processes" tab in Task Manager is incorrectly titled.  The tab named "Details" has process information.  What's listed in "Processes" is some awkward abstraction that's not very well documented.  Does the "Details" tab also list what you want to know?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500634/how-to-check-if-process-is-not-responding

Comment: @BenVoigt - I have the exe file name. Not sure about handle or process ID if the process   is in a non responsive state.

Answer (score 0):

The API's you want are:

- [**GetProcessMemoryInfo**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getprocessmemoryinfo)
- **[GetProcessTimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getprocesstimes)**

You can also see a helpful MSDN article:

> [Collecting Memory Usage Information For a Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/collecting-memory-usage-information-for-a-process) <sup>[archive](https://archive.ph/YLSbx)</sup>
>
> To determine the efficiency of your application, you may want to examine its memory usage. The following sample code uses the [**GetProcessMemoryInfo**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Psapi/nf-psapi-getprocessmemoryinfo) function to obtain information about the memory usage of a process.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <psapi.h>

// To ensure correct resolution of symbols, add Psapi.lib to TARGETLIBS
// and compile with -DPSAPI_VERSION=1

void PrintMemoryInfo( DWORD processID )
{
    HANDLE hProcess;
    PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS pmc;

    // Print the process identifier.

    printf( "\nProcess ID: %u\n", processID );

    // Print information about the memory usage of the process.

    hProcess = OpenProcess(  PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION |
                                    PROCESS_VM_READ,
                                    FALSE, processID );
    if (NULL == hProcess)
        return;

    if ( GetProcessMemoryInfo( hProcess, &pmc, sizeof(pmc)) )
    {
        printf( "\tPageFaultCount: 0x%08X\n", pmc.PageFaultCount );
        printf( "\tPeakWorkingSetSize: 0x%08X\n", 
                  pmc.PeakWorkingSetSize );
        printf( "\tWorkingSetSize: 0x%08X\n", pmc.WorkingSetSize );
        printf( "\tQuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage: 0x%08X\n", 
                  pmc.QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage );
        printf( "\tQuotaPagedPoolUsage: 0x%08X\n", 
                  pmc.QuotaPagedPoolUsage );
        printf( "\tQuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage: 0x%08X\n", 
                  pmc.QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage );
        printf( "\tQuotaNonPagedPoolUsage: 0x%08X\n", 
                  pmc.QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage );
        printf( "\tPagefileUsage: 0x%08X\n", pmc.PagefileUsage ); 
        printf( "\tPeakPagefileUsage: 0x%08X\n", 
                  pmc.PeakPagefileUsage );
    }

    CloseHandle( hProcess );
}
```

And their example procedure that uses it to enumerate all processes:

```
int main( void )
{
    // Get the list of process identifiers.

    DWORD aProcesses[1024], cbNeeded, cProcesses;
    unsigned int i;

    if ( !EnumProcesses( aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded ) )
    {
        return 1;
    }

    // Calculate how many process identifiers were returned.

    cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);

    // Print the memory usage for each process

    for ( i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++ )
    {
        PrintMemoryInfo( aProcesses[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question as stated - I should have emphasized process **STATUS**, particularly when _not responding_ is shown. Memory usage, performance, etc aren't really relevant to what I need to know. Looking for a call that will show me _**process status**_ .